# Sum of complex series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{2n}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1+i)^n}{(1+2i)^{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I want to calculate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{2n}$$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1+i)^n}{(1+2i)^{2n}}$$

First one ( for $|z| < 1$)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{2n} = -1 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z^{2})^n = -1 + \frac{1}{1-z^2}
$$
is this correct?

How can we calculate the second one?

Comment: Yes it is correct. The second one is also a geometric series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. The second one is$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1+i}{(1+2i)^2}\right)^n=\frac1{1-\frac{1+i}{(1+2i)^2}}=\frac{24-7i}{25}.$$